# InnerHTML issue Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Im working on a basic Calculator and keep having two errors involving innerHTML. I use the developer tools to debug.

The Developer tool says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null @ document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = calculate;

also "button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button" is Highlighted green.

I am a codenewbie, have no idea were my mistake is

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
  var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
  var calculate;

  if (op == "add") {
    calculate == a + b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    calculate == a - b;
  } else if (op == "mult") {
    calculate == a * b;
  } else if (op == "div") {
    calculate == a / b;
  }
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = calculate;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <form>
    Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1"> Operator:
    <select name="" id="operator">
      <option value="add">Add</option>
      <option value="min">Subtract</option>
      <option value="mult">Multiply</option>
      <option value="div">Divide</option>
    </select>
    Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <div id="results"></div>


</body>
<script src="hello.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You cannot have `script` as a child of `html`. Only `head` and  `body` are allowed there. Regarding your code problem, your `id`s mismatch. `document.querySelector("#result")` and `<div id="results"></div>`.

Answer (score -1):

The error is coming because in HTML u have given id results and in java script you are writing document.queryseletor('#result')
S is missing in java script

Comment: Please do not answer questions based on typos. Instead, comment accordingly and vote to close as typo.